# I am having trouble with batch files crashing

Tags: batch-file

I can't fix this I want to be able to write anything as a response which works with
    :being
but not
    :Fap

here is my code

```
:begin 
cls
echo You wake up and realize you are never going to amount to anything, oh      well, might as well get on with your worthless life
echo fap or vidya games
echo.
set /p input=
if /i "%input%"=="Fap" goto Fap
if /i "%input%"=="Vidya games" goto vidya games
if /i "%input%"=="vidya" goto vidya games 
if not "%input%"=="Fap"/"vidya"/"Vidya games" goto begin

:Fap
cls
echo Since you can't get a girl you decide to fantize about the girl of your   dreams so you download some watamote doujins after a mixture of crying and masterbaiting you decide to change to mood
echo vidya or sleep
echo.
set /p input=
if /i "%input%"=="vidya" goto vidya fap
if /i "%input%"=="sleep" goto sleep
if not "%input%"=="vidya"/"sleep" goto Fap
```

Comment: ...and what is your specific question? Please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Comment: He asks how to redirect to :Fap and other labels properly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Labels in batch scripts are marked by a colon like `:begin`. Same approach is used when redirecting to a certain label from IF, FOR or similar statement. So, edit your script by following this example:

```
if /i "%input%"=="Fap" (goto :Fap
) else if /i "%input%"=="Vidya" (goto :Vidya_games
) else (goto :begin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of those many `if`s, you can check, if a label exists and if yes, jump to it:

If you have several questions with different destinations, you can name your labels accordingly:

```
@echo off
:loop 
echo fap or vidya games
set /p "label=Command: "
findstr /b /i ":Q1-%label%" "%~f0" && goto :Q1-%label% 
REM previous line checks, if the label exists and if yes, jumps to it
echo no such command: %label% & goto :loop

:Q1-fap
echo reached Question1 label one.
goto :eof

:Q1-vidya
echo reached Question1 label two.
goto :eof
```

Some notes:
labels are single word only. Everything after the first space is ignored.
`findstr /i` makes it insensitive to capitalization.
`/b` searches for lines that start with the string.
`&&` means "if previous command (`findstr` here) was successful, then"
`%~f0` is the name of your batchfile.

This goes to `Q1-vidya` when you enter `vidya`, `Vidya`, `VIDYa`, `vidya Games` or `Vidya anything`.